# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload

Tags: javascript

Al momento de insertar datos a la base de datos me esta apareciendo este error.
Estuve leyendo las demás preguntas sobre este tema pero no pude dar con mi problema, en el debugger del navegador(chrome) me encuentro con esto, creo que se mezcla el json con html pero no puedo resolverlo:
*VM247:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (app.js:54)*

[image: Error XMLHttpRequest]

Comment: ES por que estas intentando pasear un texto que no es un JSON, o no tiene el formato JSON adecuado, verifica la respuesta de tu servicio en el panel de red o agrega un condicional breakpoint antes de tu JSON.parse para que veas cual es la variable con el error.

Comment: Saludos. Como muestras código ni el lado donde se genera lo que se espera sea el JSON ni tampoco la parte donde se le quiere dar tratamiento (conversión, uso, manipulación como JSON); lo más que te puedo comentar es que estas queriendo hacer uso de una estructura que **no es un JSON** como si lo fuese; lo que parece recibes es un arreglo (de 4 elementos) de arreglos (de 2 elementos).